# Finding difference between list items

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
list = [4, 7, 11, 15]
```

I'm trying to create a function to loop through list items, and find the difference between list[1] and list[0], and then list[2] and list[1], and then list[3] and list[2]... and so on for the entirety of the list. I am thinking of using a for loop but there might be a better way. Thanks.

output would be:

```
list_diff = [3, 4, 4]
```

```
def difference(list):
    for items in list():

or 

def difference(list):
    list_diff.append(list[1] - list[0])
    list_diff.append(list[2] - list[1])
etc.

...
```

Comment: maybe this - ```diffs = [b-a for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]) ]```

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Python 3.10+ you could try `pairwise`:

And you should try NOT to use the built-in *list* as the variable name.

It's quite easy and straightforward to make this one-line into a function.

```py
from itertools import pairwise

>>>[b-a for a, b in pairwise(lst)]   # List Comprehension
[3, 4, 4]

# Or just zip()
diffs = [b-a for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]) ] # no import
```

Comment: I always forget about `pairwise` - it's pretty nifty!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop for each item starting from element 1:

```py
def diff(source):
  return [source[i] - source[i - 1] for i in range(1, len(source))]

print(diff([4, 7, 11, 15])) # [3, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_list = [4, 7, 11, 15]

def difference(numbers):
    diff_list = []

    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        diff_list.append(numbers[i] - numbers[i - 1])

    return diff_list


print(difference(num_list))  # [3, 4, 4]
```